# Apply Image Effects in GLSurfaceView while i scroll it in listview or RecyclerView [Android]

Tags: android, effect

**This is the class where I set bitmap to adapter**

```
  List<ItemEffectObject> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++){
            ItemEffectObject itemObject = new ItemEffectObject();
            itemObject.setName(Effects.values()[i]);
            itemObject.setBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmapList.add(itemObject);
        }
        filterAlertAdapter = new FilterAlertAdapter(getContext(),bitmapList,mEffectContext);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(filterAlertAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2,25);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        filterAlertAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FilterAlertAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
                setCurrentEffect(Effects.values()[position]);
                mEffectView.requestRender();
            }
        });
```

**This is ItemObject Dto**

```
public class ItemEffectObject {

        Effects name;

        Bitmap bitmap;

        public Effects getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(Effects name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return bitmap;
        }

        public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
        }
}
```

**This is my RecyclerView Adapter**

I need a list of effect applying image list. While I load this code it show an exception. Thanks in advance.

> RuntimeException: Apply Wrong GL context exception

```
public class FilterAlertAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    private List<ItemEffectObject> bitmapList;
    private int mSelectedPosition = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    private int value = 10;
    private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int position;
    private GLSurfaceView.Renderer renderer = this;
    private Effects mCurrentEffect;
    private Effect mEffect;
    int mImageWidth = 0;
    int mImageHeight = 0;


    public FilterAlertAdapter(Context context, List<ItemEffectObject> bitmapList,EffectContext mEffectContext) {
        this.mEffectContext = mEffectContext;
        this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.inflater_image_filter, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder baseHolder, final int position) {
       holder = (ViewHolder)baseHolder;
                holder.mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
                holder.mEffectView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
                holder.mEffectView.setRenderer(renderer);
                holder.mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
                setCurrentEffect(bitmapList.get(position).getName());
                holder.mEffectView.requestRender();

       /* ImageLoaders imageLoader = new ImageLoaders(bitmapList.get(position).getBitmap());
        imageLoader.applyFilter(String.valueOf(bitmapList.get(position).getName()), holder.mEffectView);*/
    }

    private void setCurrentEffect(Effects effects) {
        mCurrentEffect = effects;
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            //Only need to do this once
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != Effects.NONE) {
            //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
           /* mEffect = ApplyEffects.newInstance().applyEffectOnBitmap(mCurrentEffect,mEffect,mEffectContext,mTextures,
                    mImageHeight,mImageWidth);*/
//            mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
            mTextures = ApplyEffects.newInstance().applyEffectOnBitmap(mCurrentEffect,mEffect,mEffectContext,mTextures,
                    mImageHeight,mImageWidth);
        }
        renderResult();
    }

    private void loadTextures() {
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);
        // Load input bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapList.get(position).getBitmap();
        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(holder.mEffectView.getWidth(), holder.mEffectView.getHeight());

        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Set texture parameters
        GLToolbox.initTexParams();
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != Effects.NONE) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        } else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bitmapList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

        GLSurfaceView mEffectView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.inflater_image_filter_gl);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClickListener(view, getLayoutPosition());
                mSelectedPosition = getLayoutPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(mSelectedPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        mItemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

//    public class AsyncSurfaceView extends AsyncTask<>

}
```

**This is the place to apply effects in images**

```
public class ApplyEffects {

    public static ApplyEffects newInstance(){
        return new ApplyEffects();
    }

    public int[] applyEffectOnBitmap(Effects mCurrentEffect, Effect mEffect, EffectContext mEffectContext, int[] mTextures,
                                     int mImageHeight, int mImageWidth){
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }
        // Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
        switch (mCurrentEffect) {

            case NONE:
                break;

            case AUTOFIX:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
                break;

            case MIN_MAX_COLOR_INTENSITY:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
                mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
                mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
                break;

            case BRIGHTNESS:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
                mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
                break;

            case CONTRAST:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
                mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
                break;

            case CROSS_PROCESS:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
                break;

            case DOCUMENTARY:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
                break;

            case DUO_TONE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
                mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
                mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
                break;

            case FILL_LIGHT:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
                break;

            case FISH_EYE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case FLIP_VERTICAL:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
                break;

            case FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
                break;

            case GRAIN:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
                break;

            case GRAYSCALE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
                break;

            case LOMOISH:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
                break;

            case NEGATIVE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                break;

            case POSTERIZE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                break;

            case ROTATE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
                break;

            case SATURATE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case SEPIA:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                break;

            case SHARPEN:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
                break;

            case TEMPERATURE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
                break;

            case TINT:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
                break;

            case VIGNETTE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case TINT_BLUE:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.BLUE);
                break;

            case TINT_RED:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.RED);
                break;

            case TINT_GREEN:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.GREEN);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != Effects.NONE){
            mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
        }
        return mTextures;
    }
}
```

I'm using GLSurfaceView OpenGL ES 2.0. I applying android default image effects to that bitmap list and get that bitmap list to show in sample of images like instagram sample images. below is original image what I want.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWZ41.jpg)

Comment: have you found a solution to this?